# I want to component that can change the icon to be displayed according to the name of the icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I am using typescript, react and chakra ui.
We want to display the Icon component of Twitter.ts when we pass "twitter" to the IconProps of the Icon component, and display the LinkedIn component when we pass "LinkedIn".
I want to change the icon to be displayed depending on the name passed to the Icon component.

index.tsx

```
<Icon icon="twitter"/>
```

Icon.ts

```
type Props = {
icon: string;
  fontSize?: string;
};

export const Icon: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ icon,ontSize }) => (
return ()
);
```

Facebook.ts

````
import { Icon } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
  fontSize?: string;
};

export const FacebookIcon: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ fontSize }) => (
  <Icon fontSize={fontSize}>
    <path
      fillRule="evenodd"
      clipRule="evenodd"
      d=""//  It's a long story, so I'll skip it.
    />
  </Icon>
);
```
````

Linkedin.ts

```
    import { Icon } from '@chakra-ui/react';
    import React from 'react';

    type Props = {
      fontSize?: string;
    };
    
    export const LinkedinIcon: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ fontSize }) => (
      <Icon fontSize={fontSize}>
        <path
          fillRule="evenodd"
          clipRule="evenodd"
          d=""//  It's a long story, so I'll skip it.
        />
      </Icon>
    );
```

Twitter.ts

```
    import { Icon } from '@chakra-ui/react';
    import React from 'react';

    type Props = {
      fontSize?: string;
    };
    
    export const TwitterIcon: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ fontSize }) => (
      <Icon fontSize={fontSize}>
        <path
          fillRule="evenodd"
          clipRule="evenodd"
          d=""//  It's a long story, so I'll skip it.
          fill="#525E6D"
        />
      </Icon>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the component's name as a variable, and then you can expand what icon you want.

Icon.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import FacebookIcon ...
import LinkedinIcon ...
import TwitterIcon ...

type Props = {
  icon: 'facebook' | 'linkedin' | 'twitter';
  fontSize?: string;
};

const iconMap = {
  facebook: FacebookIcon,
  linkedin: LinkedinIcon,
  twitter: TwitterIcon
}

export const Icon = ({ icon, fontSize }: Props) => {
  const CompName = iconMap[icon];

  return <CompName {...{ fontSize }} />;
};
```

Comment: Icon is not displayed.

Comment: I imported each icon, but an error message is displayed.

Comment: 'Twitter' is declared but its value is never read.ts.'Linkedin' is declared but its value is never read.ts.'Facebook' is declared but its value is never read.ts.

Comment: This snippet updated just now is available, you could try it now.

Comment: The reason why the Component Functions are never read, I guess they were removed during compilation, so I use an object to restore them.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can try it directly.